# How to set the column value to the max of that column group by another column

Tags: sql, db2, sybase

requirement....
Column A | Column B
1|23
1|25
1|26
2|4
2|5
2|6

I want to update Column B and the value should be set to the max value of group by column A. Result should be

Column A | Column B
1|26
1|26
1|26
2|6
2|6
2|6

Answer (score 1):

Try using a correlated subquery:

```
update table t
    set columnb = (select max(columnB) from table t2 where t2.columnA = t.columnA);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you'll need to use `group by` to calculate `max` values and store them in a temp table:

```
select  columnA,
        max(columnB) as maxB
into    #TMP
from    table
```

Then you can update with a simple join:

```
update  table
set     columnB = maxB
from    #TMP
where   table.columnA = #TMP.columnA
```

Hope that helps.

-Dave